# Nombre de enlace sin terminar en ".html" ni ".php"

Tags: php, html

Por lo general el nombre de un sitio web es asi: "www.nombredesitio.com/folder/pagina" en donde no se ve ningun ".html" ni tampoco ".php". ¿Cómo hacen eso o por qué sucede eso?

Comment: Echa un vistazo [por aquí](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Comment: Lo que dicen copper y dpMelian es si lo tienes que hacer manualmente, ya que ciertos frameworks como CodeIgniter y Laravel lo hacen de forma automática modificando la extensión en el archivo de configuración. 

Además, existe algo llamado "routes", con lo cual puedes modificar la url entera, incluso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se hace a través del fichero *.htaccess*

En este fichero se pueden configurar muchas directivas del servidor (no todas). En concreto la que comentas se haría así:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.html [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Si quieres poner una barra / al final sólo tienes que quitar la almohadilla de los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Si el nombre es **index** y la extensión es **html** o **php**, se puede acceder desde el nombre de la carpeta.

Ejemplos:

```
/ruta/carpeta/index.php => /ruta/carpeta
/directorio/archivo/index.html => /directorio/archivo
```

El *PHP* te devuelve el archivo *html* o *php*, a pesar de que en el navegador solo muestre el nombre de la carpeta.